# Lombok not generating getter and setter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok

First time using lombok, and if I'm understanding it correctly, lomboks getter and setter annotations generates setter and getter methods without having to code it, but for some reason I'm getting an "undefined method" error whenever I try to call a getter/setter method.

What's wrong here?

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class Student {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String firstName;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String lastName;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.setFirstName(firstName); // method undefined error here
        this.setLastName(lastName);   // method undefined error here
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `@Data` annotation on top of the class. https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/january-2010-reducing-boilerplate-code-with-project-lombok

Comment: your import wrong? `import lombok.Getter; import lombok.Setter;`

Comment: @ping.shantanu thanks for the comment. Aren't you just specifying a class level data annotation? It doesnt say anywhere that I have to add data. All the doc is stating is that Data is an annotation that includes all the characteristics of Getter, Setter ,ToString etc.

Comment: @user7294900, sorry I forgot to add the setter import in the question.

Comment: How do you compile your class? If you see the NoSuchMethodError your IDE, did you install Lombok for your IDE?

Comment: @Dan_Maff Im running the code on eclipse. It doesnt say "NoSuchMethodError", juts says The method is undefined for the type Student.

Comment: Lombok setup for Eclipse:
https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sould work as this,
Did you install lombok's plugin on your EDI ?

Comment: Lombok plugin was in fact, not installed in my IDE. 
I assumed it was installed case it wasn`t saying any errors on the import. 

Thanks @Clint Magnus and @Dan_Maff

My apologies friends.

Comment: To learn how to resolve Lambok not generating getters and setters, please refer to https://paulsofts.com/lombok-is-not-generating-getters-and-setter/

Answer (score 2):

Lombok was not installed in my IDE.

Installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is to use the `@Data` annotation, which generates getters and setters for every property in your class.

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

Quick note: importing something doesn't use it. It simply tells the program something *may* be used. If you are using a modern Java IDE (VSCode or IntelliJ), classes, annotations, etc. will be automatically imported as you use them.

Comment: this does not answer the question. It just repeats the problem with other annotation used.

Answer (score 0):

|*| Enable Annotation Processing :

|*> @Data from Lombok to work

|+> In top bar Click on "Project

|+> Click on "Properties"

|+> In Left Menu Bar -> Goto "Maven"

|+> Select "Annotation Processing"

|+> [O] Checkmark "Enable project specific settings"

|+> Click on "Apply"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Lombok Plugin in the ide

Comment: Doesn't add any new information.

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
@Getter
 @Setter
public class Student {
   
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
    
        this.setFirstName(firstName); 
        this.setLastName(lastName);  
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).